# How can I specify 4 different start and end dates for previous year and current year all specifying the 1st day of the month using SET?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I am trying to make SET variables in SnowSQL that will specify the first of each start month and end month for the current year and previous years respectively. I want the code to be able to roll over to the new month as time progresses. So for example, since it is June 2020 we would have m2_start = 2020-06-01 and m2_end = 2020-07-01. m1_start = 2019-06-01 and m1_end 2019-07-01. Here is what I have so far, but it is not quiet what I want as I can't figure out how to specify on the first of the month:

SET m1_start = (SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(year,-1,CURRENT_DATE) FROM DIMDATE d WHERE DAY(d."Date") = 1);

SET m1_end = (SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(month, -11,CURRENT_DATE) FROM DIMDATE d WHERE DAY(d."Date") = 1);

SET m2_start = (SELECT d."Date" FROM DIMDATE d WHERE DAY(d."Date") = 1 AND MONTH(d."Date") = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) AND YEAR(d."Date") = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE));

SET m2_end = (SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(month, 1,CURRENT_DATE) FROM DIMDATE d WHERE DAY(d."Date") = 1);

SET Test = '2020-06-01';

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified using [`DATE_ADD(…)`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html), [`DATE_TRUNC(…)`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html) and [`ADD_MONTHS(…)`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/add_months.html) purpose-specific [date/time functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time.html).

> I can't figure out how to specify on the first of the month:

The `DATE_TRUNC(…)` function lets you chop-down any date to the beginning of any of its parts. When run with the `month` part, it will yield a date equal to the beginning of the month.

A minimal example:

```sql
SET _current_date = (SELECT CURRENT_DATE);
SET _last_year_date = (SELECT DATEADD(year, -1, $_current_date));

SET m2_start = (SELECT DATE_TRUNC(month, $_current_date));
SET m2_end = (SELECT ADD_MONTHS($m2_start, 1));

SET m1_start = (SELECT DATE_TRUNC(month, $_last_year_date));
SET m1_end = (SELECT ADD_MONTHS($m1_start, 1));

-- Alternatively, you can derive m1_* values by subtracting a year from m2_*
-- values, but it felt too intermingled
-- SET m1_start = (SELECT DATE_ADD(year, -1, $m2_start));
-- SET m1_end = (SELECT DATE_ADD(year, -1, $m2_end));
```

Example output when executed on `2020-06-24`:

```sql
> SELECT $_current_date, $_last_year_date, $m1_start, $m1_end, $m2_start, $m2_end;

+----------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| $_CURRENT_DATE | $_LAST_YEAR_DATE | $M1_START  | $M1_END    | $M2_START  | $M2_END    |
|----------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------|
| 2020-06-23     | 2019-06-23       | 2019-06-01 | 2019-07-01 | 2020-06-01 | 2020-07-01 |
+----------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kirby! Not only did you provide an answer but explained too. I can't thank you enough for the assistance! 7.5 months in to learning SQL and DDL has tripped me up a little.